# How to perform SAML authentication with Spring and SAP Cloud Platform

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, saml, sap-cloud-platform

I am trying to implement Programmatic Authentication as described here https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/e637f62abb571014857cb0232adc43a7.html#loio778d8987e7714376977c190f6df379ad

However, I don't want to implement a servlet by hand, I want to use Spring instead.

Here is my authentication provider:

```
import com.sap.security.auth.login.LoginContextFactory;

@Component
public class FormAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractJaasAuthenticationProvider {

    private final static String FORM = "FORM";
    {
        setAuthorityGranters(new AuthorityGranter[] {
            new AuthorityGranter() {

                @Override
                public Set<String> grant(Principal principal) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected LoginContext createLoginContext(CallbackHandler handler) throws LoginException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return LoginContextFactory.createLoginContext(FORM);
    }

}
```

And the web security configurer adapter:

```
public static class FormWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private FormAuthenticationProvider formAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(formAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable() //HTTP with Disable CSRF
                .antMatcher("/form")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }
}
```

With this implementation, I am redirected to a Java login form, when I want to be redirected to the SAP ID service.

The classic `web.xml` method with `<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>` successfully redirects to SAP ID service, I thought that Spring's `formLogin()` was an equivalent.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is this related to SAML-based SSO? Reading the linked documentation, it seems this is simple userid/password authentication and not SSO.

Comment: The `FORM` method default behavior is to redirect to a login form, and expose a `POST` endpoint to retrieve the credentials. By using the `FORM` `LoginContext` from the SAP library, it should redirect to SAP ID service and expose a `POST` endpoint to retrieve the SAML response

Comment: Actually SAML does not work like that. If there is an SAP SAML-IdP, then your app should act as a SAML-SP. You can then just use spring-saml-security in your Spring Boot app. When accessing the app, SAML SP-initiated SSO flow is triggered.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a working sample?

Comment: The Spring-security SAML extension docs have a sample using ssocirlce.net as IdP